# Turn system icons (notifications) on/off resets on restart

Tags: windows-8, notification-area

I noticed that when I turn off some of the the language input indicator in the system icons / notifications area, it doesn't save the state and turns back on on restart. Is this a known issue? What could be causing this?

Specifically what I'm referring to:

- In notifications area, click the small arrow
- Click Customize
- Click "Turn system icons on or off"

[image]

I noticed a [comment](http://www.technoon.com/how-to-turn-off-system-icons-in-windows-8.html) here says the change is for the session only. Why would that be intended behavior...?

How else can I turn the language input indicator off permanently? (It takes an awful lot of space).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to Control Panel → Clock, Language, and Region → Language → Advanced Settings
2. Under "Switching Input Methods" make sure that "Use the desktop language bar when it's available" is checked
3. Click the Options link to its right. A new window should pop up.
4. Go to the "Language Bar" tab and set "Language Bar" to Hidden
5. Finally hit OK and Save

Comment: This seems to do the trick - Enable as Hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Turning them off isn't session only and (for me) it stays off unless I change it back.

Maybe there is something else that is turning on your input indicator icon?

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what would that be. On my initial install, everything(metro apps, web page redirects, etc.) ended up in French, so I messed with settings around a bit to change it back to English (I only wanted French keyboard and French date/time formats like I'm used to in Win7). Languages are fixed, but this thing can't stay off. Hope I can figure it out without having to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, they fixed the "only save for this session" thing in Windows 7. If you want to get rid of it, go to Control Panel > Languages (sorry, not at a Windows PC at the moment) and delete all other languages except for your current one. If I remember rightly, there's an option there to hide the taskbar indicator off too.

Comment: I've already deleted extra languages (there's only one big row in Languages with the "Options" button), but I've kept 2 keyboard input languages which I need.

Comment: Try turning it off from System Notifications again, then restarting immediately.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what fixed it, but after going through most language preferences and changing settings back and forth (language override, show/hide language bar, etc.) it doesn't show up anymore on boot.